# How do you programatically set the source switch with System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics

I have a situation where I need to capture the trace from System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.  Currently I have a custom trace listner configurered like so in code:

```
    _traceListener = new InMemoryTraceListener();
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(_traceListener);
```

and in the app.config I have the source switch configured like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Workflow.Activities.Rules" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This works and I am able to capture the race messages in my custom trace listener.  I need the trace information as it is critical to the overall solution and is set at the level required.

But as I need to configure the switch programatically instead of through configuration as its going into a dll for the GAC.

I have tried a number of different things with SourceSwitch and TraceSource but none of them have worked for me.

**Edit:** In summary I want to programatically configure a switch for an existing source from the .net framework so that I can listen to trace messages.

Answer (score 3):

I have adapted some code that I came across that does something similar. It sets the switch via reflection on a non public method. It isn't best practice, but is there another better way?

```
 #region Dodgy dodgy hackery. There has to be a better way of doing this ....
 var trace = typeof(System.Workflow.Activities.StateActivity)
                .Assembly
                .GetType("System.Workflow.Activities.WorkflowActivityTrace");

 var rules = trace.GetProperty("Rules", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                .GetValue(null, null)
                as System.Diagnostics.TraceSource;

 rules.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Information;

 rules.Listeners.Clear();
 rules.Listeners.Add(_traceListener);
 #endregion
```

Comment: this is an awesome approach(hacky yes, but still) i'm attempting the same with SignalR, but the traces are instance properties inside, so i may need to locate the instantiated TraceSources. So this solution is close, but not always enough

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the [TraceSource (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and do something like

```
TraceSource mySource = new TraceSource("MySource");
mySource.Listeners.Add(new InMemoryTraceListener());
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I thought that you would use a TraceSource when you were writing trace messages in your code rather than listening to trace messages coming from a .net framework source?